# Powershell Run process output in a separate window for each line

Tags: powershell

I have the following powershell script which I am using to run a Plink command on 3 of my servers remotely (i have all correct privileges)

```
$KAFKA_PATH = "/opt/kafka"
$KAFKA_PROP_FILE = $KAFKA_PATH + "/config/server.properties"
$ZK_PROP_FILE = $KAFKA_PATH + "/config/zookeeper.properties"
$KAFKA_START = $KAFKA_PATH + "/bin/kafka-server-start.sh"
$ZK_START = $KAFKA_PATH + "/bin/zookeeper-server-start.sh"
echo Y | plink -i $HOME\Documents\keys\authorized_key_priv.ppk secret1server -t "bash $ZK_START $ZK_PROP_FILE &"
timeout /t 5                                                                                            
echo Y | plink -i $HOME\Documents\keys\authorized_key_priv.ppk secret2server -t "bash $ZK_START $ZK_PROP_FILE &"
timeout /t 5                                                                                                                                 
echo Y | plink -i $HOME\Documents\keys\authorized_key_priv.ppk secret3server -t "bash $ZK_START $ZK_PROP_FILE &"
timeout /t 10                                                                                            
echo Y | plink -i $HOME\Documents\keys\authorized_key_priv.ppk secret1server -t "bash $KAFKA_START $KAFKA_PROP_FILE &"
timeout /t 5                                                                                             
echo Y | plink -i $HOME\Documents\keys\authorized_key_priv.ppk secret2server -t "bash $KAFKA_START $KAFKA_PROP_FILE &"
timeout /t 5                                                                                             
echo Y | plink -i $HOME\Documents\keys\authorized_key_priv.ppk secret3server -t "bash $KAFKA_START $KAFKA_PROP_FILE &"
```

but I cannot see the logs correctly, also some of them seem to become frozen and causes the subsequent ones not to run correctly. All I want is each of the plink commands to run in a seperate window so that I can see each of them erroring out or running correctly. I understand that the ampersand (&) means I am daemonizing it, but that's okay I can remove it if I need to see the console outs.

Any help will be appreciated.

THanks,

Comment: Wouldn't you keep a better overview running tmux under WSL/bash [link1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29311105/running-the-same-command-on-several-ssh-servers-using-tmux), [link2](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/298702/run-command-in-multiple-active-shells-simultaneously)

Answer (score 1):

hmm....silly myself is all what I can say

What I didn't understand was that I wanted it as a command (remote/local doesn't matter) so it has be treated as a command. When I did the following, i saw a new window with console output

```
echo Y | cmd /c start plink -i $HOME\Documents\keys\authorized_key_priv.ppk secret1server -t ""bash $KAFKA_START $KAFKA_PROP_FILE ""&"""
```

it worked as expected. But may be this is not the right solution?

Answer (score 0):

See if any of the info in this discussion gives you other ideas.

> [Windows-to-Linux: Execute a shell script as user process (as bkgrnd) on remote machines](https://superuser.com/questions/1338006/windows-to-linux-execute-a-shell-script-as-user-process-as-bkgrnd-on-remote-m/1338074#1338074)

Though your goal is a bit different than the OP from that one.